# Unable to find path to the Windows resource compiler C++ UE4

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

An error occurred while trying to generate project files.

```
Running D:/DevOps/UE_4.26/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe  -projectfiles -project="D:/DevOps/Unreal_Projects_4.26/MyProject1/MyProject1.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
Discovering modules, targets and source code for project...
ERROR: Unable to find path to the Windows resource compiler under C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10 (version 10.0.18362.0)
```

Comment: So, what is your question and what have you done to solve the problem so far?

Answer (score 0):

VS 2017 installation helped me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).